# How to pass a second variable from routes.php to a controller in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have the following route defined in `routes.php` in Laravel 5:

```
Route::get('records/{id}', 'RecordController@show');
```

However, I'd like to have a similar route which is something like:

```
Route::get('masterrecord/{id}', 'RecordController@show[masterrecord=true]');
```

(The [masterrecord=true] bit is invented and doesn't work)

When I open a 'masterrecord' then I'd like to exact same function in the controller (**show** function in RecordController), but I'd like to pass an extra parameter (something like 'masterrecord = true') which would make a slight change in the functionality. I known I could refer to a different function but I really don't want to be repeating the same code.

Here is the kind of thing I'd *like* to have in RecordController but I'm not sure how to make it work:

```
public function show($id, $masterrecord = false)
```

And then for the `records/id` routes I would leave masterrecord to be false, and for the `masterrecord/id` routes I'd be able to mark the second flag as true.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to you can pass a hardcoded value in the route definition. Then you can pull it from the route's action array. Gives you another option.

```
Route::get('masterrecord/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'RecordController@show',
    'masterrecord' => true,
]);

public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $action = $request->route()->getAction();

    if (isset($action['masterrecord'])) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Adjust naming how ever you want.

[asklagbox blog - random tips and tricks for laravel](http://asklagbox.com/blog/random-tips-tricks#routing-hardcoded-values)

Answer (score 0):

Just make the value optional and set it by deafult

```
Route::get('masterrecord/{id}/{masterrecord?}', 'RecordController@show');
```

Controller:

```
public function show($id, $masterrecord = false) {
    if($masterrecord) // only when passed in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be repeating any code, just have a master-record method that calls the `show` method:

```php
Route::get('records/{id}', 'RecordController@show');
Route::get('masterrecord/{id}', 'RecordController@showMasterRecord');
```

```php
public function show($id, $master = false) {
    if ($master) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

public function showMasterRecord($id) {
    return $this->show($id, true);
}
```